# FPDF skips first row

Tags: php, fpdf

I wrote a simple [**FPDF**](http://www.fpdf.org/) code but I ran into a problem.

For some reason, the *for loop* skips the first row ( cell 1, cell 2, cell 3 ).

**Code:**

```
<?php
require('temp/fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF
{
    function Header(){
        $this->SetY(0);
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
        $this->Cell(0,5,'Page '.$this->PageNo(),0,0,'C');
    }

    function Footer(){
        $this->SetY(-5);
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
        $this->Cell(0,5,'Page '.$this->PageNo(),0,0,'C');
    }
}

$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->SetMargins(0,0,0);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
for($i=0;$i<=24;$i++){
    $pdf->Cell(70,30,'Printing line number '.$i,0,0,'C');

    if(($i%3==0)&&($i!=0)){
        $pdf->Ln();
    }
}

$pdf->Output();
?>
```

[image: Problem]

I'm staring at the code for hours but I can't find the answer so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first set of printing is floating over to the right side. As a quick-fix try adding to add a line break and clear up unwanted floats in the PDF definition.

Add

```
$pdf->Ln();
```

after

```
$pdf->AddPage();
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities that you might want to check. The first is that the margins are all zero, but in order for a PDF to print or save correctly, they need to be 1" on top/bottom and .5" on the sides. Also you have to consider that the first iteration of your loop $i will equal 0, and your first cell will print out 0 and not 1. Let me know if that doesn't pan out, and I can help more. I'm actually in the middle of a huge FPDF project and have found many nuances.

I just noticed this:

```
if(($i%3==0)&&($i!=0)){
    $pdf->Ln();
}
```

Use this http://calculator.sdsu.edu/calculator.php to calculate the Modulus using your $i values and you'll see 0%3=0, 1%3=4, 2%3=5. That will skip your first line.

I personally would've written it like this:

```
$i = 1;
while($i <=25)
{
    $pdf->Cell(70,30,'Printing line number '.$i,0,0,'C');

    if(($i % 3) == 0)
    {
        $pdf->Ln();
    }
}
```

Comment: Changed both but the result is the same.

Comment: Still, I changed `$i=0` with `$i=4` ant the result is the same only this time it starts from **7**.

Comment: Can you change the value of $i to start with 1 if you're going to leave that IF condition in your code that skips over the first iteration?